# Sorting list of lists in CYPHER

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How should we sort list of tuples in cypher .

```
MATCH (n) 
WHERE EXISTS(n.docId)
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT [n.docId,n.senId]) as docs ORDER BY docs[0]
RETURN docs
```

The above query returns :

```
[[848613, 1], [848613, 2], [848514, 1], [90029, 2], [848681, 1], [575833, 2], [847627, 1], [849538, 2]]
```

What is the efficient way to achieve this sorted result :

```
[[90029, 2],[849538, 2],[848681, 1],[848613, 1],[848613, 2],[848514, 1],[847627, 1],[575833, 2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried around and figured out this answer :

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE EXISTS(n.docId)
WITH DISTINCT [n.docId,n.senId] as  ds ORDER BY ds[0],ds[1]
  WITH COLLECT(ds) as docs 
    RETURN docs
```

Comment: That is correct. The order by have to precede the colect statement.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simpler form of @sus's answer:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE EXISTS(n.docId)
WITH DISTINCT [n.docId, n.senId] as ds ORDER BY ds
RETURN COLLECT(ds) as docs
```